# Against Historical (or Geographical) Determinism

Tags: philosophy-of-science, determinism, history

It seems that determinism has gained tremendously in terms of being accepted as a general theory of everything by a large number of people. Books like *The Selfish Gene* and *Guns, Germs, and Steel* have done a lot to push the cause forward to the public imagination.

I however am deeply sceptical about its validity and in some cases even its use, mainly in the areas of social theory and history.

Can anyone suggest any good resources (books, articles etc.) that counters this view, especially in the real of history?

Comment: Maybe interesting Harm de Blij's books, like e.g. [The Power of Place : Geography, Destiny, and Globalization's Rough Landscape](https://books.google.it/books?id=FfaktAEACAAJ) (2008) : he is a *geographer*.

Comment: "Geographic determinism", as you use it, confuses two different things. The 19th century idea of geography being largely determinative of human culture and history is [disavowed by neo-"determinists" like Diamond](http://www.jareddiamond.org/Jared_Diamond/Geographic_determinism.html). What they do assert is much harder to deny, that climate, terrain, etc., have *some* influence on human practices. A major critique is [Neo-Environmental Determinism by Guss and Meyer](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-54232-4_5).

Comment: @Conifold Thanks but it does not offer what I need. The article you attached does not disavows GD, it simply states that history is more complicated than that. The other seems to largely agree. I am looking at something that shows how culture and environment are form such a feedback loop that one cannot privilege the other without committing a scientific error.

Comment: That is one of Guss-Meyer's points, e.g. "*Poverty greatly increases vulnerability to extreme natural events and is plausibly much more the cause of the disparity in impact than its effect*", p.69. They also describe many other problems with geographic determinism beyond its base/superstructure scheme, such as circular reasoning, neglected confounders, selective correlating, etc. Their critique is quite severe. And they have extensive references to multiple other critics, including Blaut, the "*most incisive critic of neo-determinism*".

Comment: @Conifold Sure, but geography might still explain WHY they were poor in the first place, so smoothing the edges by saying that it’s not all determined by geography is not what I am looking for. What I am looking for goes more to the direction of aesthetic attitudes determining what people do, geography providing the material. I am looking for fundamental flaws in the basic assumptions of determinism, not just occasional errors.

Comment: It seems that you did not read the paper since this is not what it is saying, and "fundamental flaws" is exactly what it is about (unless you mean something so "fundamental" that it does not exist, determinism does apply in some situations). "Aesthetic attitudes determining what people do, geography providing the material" is too cryptic for me to understand. If it is aesthetic attitudes that determine history then how would geography provide the material? If you are simply looking for an aestheticist view of history try [Spengler](https://www.ihr.org/jhr/v17/v17n2p-2_Stimely.html).

Comment: @Conifold I mean it in the same way as it applies it art. Recently I read in the Telegraph that Monet's style can be explained by his cataract. This is hard determinism: Monet he painted this way because he was "forced" to do so by his body. That assumes that all painters paint just what they see and lack the ability to reshape reality according to their aesthetic. I believe that Monet wanted to express something about the world and used what he saw (cataract or not) to do so. His vision provided the material he shaped into an aesthetic.

Comment: Telegraph is not exactly a place of historical scholarship, so we should not expect careful phrasing, but the statement can be interpreted without "hard determinism". Cataract was part of Monet's life, it influenced his sight and its effects conceivably (I do not know if this was actually studied) played a role in his art, shaped and channeled through other traits of his personality of course. It is just as unlikely that Monet had some fixed "internal vision", detached from his body and environment, that "came through" in his works as that everybody with a cataract would paint like Monet.

Comment: @Conifold Ok, so at least now you understand what I meant by aesthetic attitudes using the material available, right?

Comment: I still do not get what it has to do with "geography providing the material". Material for "inner vision"??? And I am even more puzzled as to why you asked for criticism of determinism (which has nothing to do with aestheticism specifically) instead of works connecting events to "aesthetic attitudes", for example.

Comment: @Conifold Providing the material means: If there is marble, you will use marble, but it does not dictate HOW you will use it. This is up to aesthetics which in my view are NOT reducible. I am just trying to find the intellectual substratum for my instinctive view. Same goes with Monet. His cataract gave him the "material," presented him with a series of images that were particularly distorted. WHAT he did with them was not the contact's doing. The reason I mentioned the Telegraph was just to show that these views are becoming dominant in the public's eye. Like determinism in general is.

Comment: This sounds closest to [Aristotle's distinction between material and final causes](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-causality/#FouCau), which he motivated by the process of art creation.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks! This seems like what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm not reading your question in the correct context, but one theory against determinism would be "human action".

So basically it's [***Free Will*** vs. ***Determinism***](http://www.thegreatdebate.org.uk/determinismandfreewill.html)

*Do changes in the material conditions of life determine change? OR Does human action create and change the material conditions of life?*

This might be more in the realm of anthropology than philosophy. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, this is more or less it. What resources would you suggest?